# In a for loop with the objective of automatically returning count plots for all categorical variables, how would you filter data for only cat columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

This is what my code looks like:

```
for i in penguins.columns:
    if penguins[i].dtype == 'category':
        plt.figure(figsize=(16,8)),
        sns.countplot(x=i, data=penguins,  palette='flare'),
        plt.show()
```

But it returns this error and only gives me one plot:
'data type 'category' not understood'

Comment: `for i in penguins.columns:
    if penguins[i].dtype.name== 'category':
        plt.figure(figsize=(16,8)),
        sns.countplot(x=i, data=cgf,  palette='flare'),
        plt.show()`                                        ####Found it.

Comment: There is also https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_categorical_dtype.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Pandas allows direct comparisons of dtypes with strings; the `'categorical'` string would be equal to `pd.CategoricalDtype.name`.

You could try one of the following:

```
for col in penguins:
    if penguins[col].dtype == pd.CategoricalDtype:
        plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
        sns.countplot(x=i,
                      data=penguins,
                      palette='flare')

plt.show()
```

or

```
for col in penguins:
    if penguins[col].dtype.name == 'categorical':
        plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
        sns.countplot(x=i,
                      data=penguins,
                      palette='flare')

plt.show()
```